# Why is the dropdown going under the DIV instead of over

Tags: html, css

I have this website: http://www.westmedgroup.com/find_provider.aspx

From the left dropdown menu, it keeps going under which prevents the entire list to be shown.

I set a `min-height` as well as `overflow: visible` but none of them are working.

Please help me resolve it.

Comment: I can't find the menu you are talking about. Can you post an image?

Comment: Click on "Select Language:", I think that is what he means. Any of the left select options.

Comment: I can't find the menu, or the "select language" link... Give us another clue, please.

Comment: Or any of the dropdown. I had to add "min-height: 750px;" to fix it but is there anyway for it to overflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this when inspecting your page

```
.hidOverflow {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

unchecking this fixed the problem

Comment: Not sure how I added it back again. Thanks for the help :)